# About the GNU make dependency files *.d

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the makefile of a program, one has to write rules that define the dependencies of each object file. Consider the object file `fileA.o`. It is obvious that this object file depends on the source file `fileA.c`. But it will also depend on all the header files that this source file includes. So the following rule should be added to the makefile:

```
    # This rule states that fileA.o depends on fileA.c (obviously), but also
    # on the header files fileA.h, fileB.h and fileC.h
    fileA.o: fileA.c fileA.h fileB.h fileC.h
```

Note that the rule has no recipe. One could add a recipe to it, but it is strictly speaking not necessary, because GNU make can rely on an implicit rule (with recipe) to compile a `*.c` file into a `*.o` file.

Anyway, writing such rules manually is a hellish task. Just imagine the work to keep the makefile rules in sync with the #include statements from the source code.

The GNU make manual describes in chapter 4.14 "Generating Prerequisites Automatically" a methodology to automate this procedure. The procedure starts with the generation of a `*.d` file for each source file. I quote:

> For each source file **name.c** there is a makefile **name.d** which lists what files the object file **name.o** depends on.

The manual proceeds:

> Here is the pattern rule to generate a file of prerequisites (i.e, a makefile) called **name.d** from a C source file called **name.c** :

```
    %.d: %.c
        @set -e; rm -f $@; \
         $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
         rm -f $@.$$$$
```

Sadly, the manual does not explain in detail how this rule actually works. Yes, it gives the desired **name.d** file, but why? The rule is very obfuscated..

When looking at this rule, I get the feeling that its recipe will only run smoothly on Linux. Am I right? Is there a way to make this recipe run correctly on Windows as well?

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Exit on all errors

```
@set -e;
```

Delete existing dep file (`$@` = target = `%.d`)

```
rm -f $@;
```

Have the compiler generate the dep file and output to a temporary file postfixed with the shell pid (`$<` = first prerequisite = `%.c`, `$$$$` -> `$$` -> pid)

```
$(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;
```

Capture the target matching `$*.o` (`$*` = match stem = `%`), replace it with the target followed by the dependency file itself, output to dep file

```
sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
```

Delete temp dep

```
rm -f $@.$$$$
```

Let's plug in `foo`, `CC = gcc`, and `CPPFLAGS = ''` to see what happens after make has finished expanding stuff:

```
foo.d: foo.c
    @set -e; rm -f foo.d; \
     gcc -M foo.c > foo.d.$$; \
     sed 's,\(foo\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o foo.d : ,g' < foo.d.$$ > foo.d; \
     rm -f foo.d.$$
```

The shell itself will expand `$$` to the pid, and the final rule in the dep file will look something like

```
foo.o foo.d : foo.c foo.h someheader.h
```

---

Note that this is a pretty outdated way of generating dependencies, if you're using GCC or clang you can [generate them](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) as part of compilation itself with `CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP`.

Say you have a program called `foo`:

```
objs := foo.o bar.o
deps := $(objs:.o=.d)

vpath %.c $(dir $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

foo: $(objs)

.PHONY: clean
clean: ; $(RM) foo $(objs) $(deps)

-include $(deps)
```

That's all you need, the built-in rules will do the rest. Obviously things will be a little more complicated if you want the object files in a different folder or if you want to build outside the source tree.

The `vpath` directive allows you to run make in a different directory and have the files created there, e.g. `make -f path/to/source/Makefile`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for all the explanations. I'm still working through your explanations to fully understand. But you definitely gave me a big boost :-)

Comment: I'm using the GCC compiler indeed. So there is a more elegant way to generate dependencies? Could you describe it? I'm a bit shy to ask this, because I know this will probably consume a lot of your time. But I would be soooo grateful :-)

Comment: @K.Mulier Added a short example.

Comment: Waw, thank you so much for this example. Unfortunately, I would like to 'build outside the source tree'. In this way, I keep the source folder(s) uncluttered. But to be honest, I have no idea on how to generate the dependencies for that

Comment: There are several ways to do "outside the source tree" builds -- either put paths on the .o and .d files to put them elsewhere while you build in the source tree, or use VPATH or paths on the sources and build in an object-only tree.

Comment: @K.Mulier I edited the example to support out of tree builds, it's fairly naïve but should work nonetheless.

Comment: Hi user657267 and @Chris Dodd , I have started a new Stackoverflow question on the topic of out-of-source builds. Please take a look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make  
Your help is very much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Responding to K Mulier:
Try:

```
gmake -C $workdir ...
```

That sets

```
CURDIR = ${workdir}
```

but leaves $PWD (from env) alone.
All temp/output files are created in ${workdir}.
Also, I set the variable $. = ${PWD} and use that to specify anything relative to the dir in which gmake was run (i.e. the source dir).
So, instead of

```
CPPFLAGS += -I../include
```

there is

```
CPPFLAGS += -I$.  -I$./../include
```