# Makefile with Dynamic Output Directory Based on Source File Directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a Makefile using a [monorepo](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md) and am struggling a bit with dynamic output directories based on the source files' directories.

My project is laid out like so:

```
% tree .
.
├── Makefile
└── packages
    ├── bar
    │   └── src
    │       └── index.js
    │       └── other-file.js
    └── foo
        └── src
            └── index.js

5 directories, 4 files
```

I want to process each `*.js` file inside of each package (e.g., `./packages/foo/src/index.js`) and emit the output into another directory (specifically, `./packages/foo/lib/index.js`).

For example `make bar` would:

- Process `./packages/bar/src/index.js` -> `./packages/bar/lib/index.js`
- Process `./packages/bar/src/other-file.js` -> `./packages/bar/lib/other-file.js`

I would also potentially like to use this pattern for other sorts of files in `./src` such as processing `.less` files.

**Makefile**:

```
PACKAGES_ROOT = ./packages
packages := $(shell ls $(PACKAGES_ROOT))

package_source_dir := $(addprefix packages/,$(addsuffix /src/,$(packages)))
package_dest_dir := $(subst src,lib,$(package_source_dir))

package_source := $(foreach sdir, $(package_source_dir), $(wildcard $(sdir)*.js*))
package_dest := $(subst src,lib,$(package_source))

.PHONY: all checkdirs clean
all: checkdirs

checkdirs: $(package_dest_dir)

$(package_dest_dir):
    mkdir -p $@

$(packages):
    @echo "$@"

clean:
    rm -rf $(package_dest_dir)
```

I'm not sure if I need to use `VPATH` or what ... help?

Note: The `Makefile` currently is just enough to make and remove all destination directories.

Comment: Though your question is not fully a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make/39033569#39033569), you can find here a few different methods to achieve what you want to do. Take the time to read and understand the answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had actually made an attempt at dynamic rule generation, but my `define` was never getting called. Will give it another go, and update my question (and hopefully answer) with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
# Directories
PKGS_ROOT := packages
PKGS_SRCDIR := src
PKGS_OUTDIR := lib

# Expands to the source directory for the specified package
pkg-srcdir = $(PKGS_ROOT)/$1/$(PKGS_SRCDIR)
# Expands to the output directory for the specified package
pkg-libdir = $(PKGS_ROOT)/$1/$(PKGS_OUTDIR)
# Expands to all output targets for the specified package
pkg-libs = $(addprefix $(call pkg-libdir,$1)/,$(notdir $(wildcard $(call pkg-srcdir,$1)/*.js)))

# Defines the following rules for the specified package:
#  - build rule for .js files
#  - rule to create the output directory if missing
#  - package rule to build all outputs
#  - clean-package rule to remove the output directory
# Adds the following prerequisites:
#  - package target to 'all' rule
#  - clean-package target to 'clean' rule
define pkg-rules
$(call pkg-libdir,$1)/%.js: $(call pkg-srcdir,$1)/%.js | $(call pkg-libdir,$1)
    @echo Making $$@ from $$^
    @cp $$^ $$@
$(call pkg-libdir,$1):
    @mkdir $$@
$1: $(call pkg-libs,$1)
clean-$1:
    rm -rf $(call pkg-libdir,$1)
all: $1
clean: clean-$1
.PHONY: $1 clean-$1
endef

# Creates rules for the specified package
add-pkg = $(eval $(call pkg-rules,$1))

# Create rules for all packages
PKGS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(PKGS_ROOT)/*))
$(foreach p,$(PKGS),$(call add-pkg,$p))

# Will be filled in by pkg-rules
.PHONY: all clean

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

The individual functions/helpers/manipulation shouldn't be hard to understand. I abstracted directories into the first three helpers to avoid having to change a ton of occurrences should the need arise. Let's dive in `pkg-rules` where the actual dynamic rules are defined.

Say `pkg-rules` gets passed `foo`. It will create the following rules:

- `packages/foo/lib/%.js: packages/foo/src/%.js | packages/foo/lib`: this is the pattern rule that builds the output `.js` file. It also has the output directory as an order-only prerequisite (which has nothing to do with execution order - it means the directory target will be built only if it doesn't exist, without looking at the timestamp).
- `packages/foo/lib`: this rule creates the output directory. You don't have nested directories and the recipe won't be executed if the directory exists, so `-p` is not needed. By the way, it's possible to have nested directories and replicate the source tree, but it requires some more trickery (likely secondary expansion, `$(@D)`, using a more clever `patsubst` in place of `notdir`, using the shell for recursive wildcards, extracting dirs, etc).
- `foo: packages/foo/lib/index.js`: in the comments I call this the "package target/rule". It's an empty phony rule which has all the package outputs as prerequisites.
- `clean-foo`: in the comments I call this "clean-package target/rule". It's a phony rule which removes the package output directory.

It will also add the package and clean-package targets as prerequisites to the generic `all` and `clean` rules.

Targets like `foo`, `clean-bar`, `all` and `clean` will behave exactly like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a temporary makefile:

```
packages:= $(shell ls $(PACKAGES_ROOT))

packages.mk : Makefile $(abspath .)
    for package in $(packages); do \
        echo "packages/$(package)/lib/%.js:packages/$(package)/src/%.js" >> $@ ; \
        echo "    echo recipe for $(dir)" >> $@; \
        echo >> $@; \
    done

-include "packages.mk"
```

This assumes that the directories are not dynamically created by other rules, as `$(packages)` will only contain the directories which were present when the makefile was first read.