# Compile several programs in the subdirectories of a directory and place the executables in different directories using makefile

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make

my problem is this: I want to create a makefile which will compile programs in several directories but will place executables in the subdirectory named **executables** in each of the directories. I have a huge number of programs to be compiled so writing rules for each of them seems tedious. Assuming that my current working directory is **Curr_dir** following is the directory structure-

```
Curr_dir
    |
    |__dir1
    |   |__q1.c
    |   |__q2.c
    |   |__q3.c
    |   |__+executable
    |
    |__dir2
    |   |__q4.c
    |   |__q5.c
    |   |__q6.c
    |   |__+executable
    |
    |__Makefile
```

I have listed down only 2 directories in my root directory but there are several directories containing 3-4 .c files. Now I want to compile all these .c files using Makefile in my root directory and place the executables in the corresponding **executables** directories.
Here is my makefile, which compiles each of the programs and generates executable in the same directory.

```
CC= gcc
RM= rm -vrf
CFLAGS= -lm -g
SRCFILES =$(wildcard */*.c)
SRCDIRS= $(wildcard */)
EXECDIRS= $(SRCDIRS:%=%executables)
EXECFILES = $(SRCFILES:%.c=%)
dirs: 
    mkdir -p $(EXECDIRS)

all: dirs $(EXECFILES)

%: %.c
    -$(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
     $(RM) $(EXECFILES) $(EXECDIRS)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: cant you compile with the full path to each file and then use mv ?

Comment: @proton: I could do that but with the current makefile that I have, I can't think how that can be achieved. I have edited the question with my makefile code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: It's really easy to have multiple source directories, just put them in the `VPATH` variable, then `make` will look for the sources in these folders. What is complicated is to place the output files in multiple directories. See [GNU make documentation about VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)

Comment: @TimF: If you look closely, that's what my current makefile does by assigning all sourcefiles to SRCFILES and executables (with the name as basename of the sourcefile and path same as source-path) to EXECFILES.

Comment: I don't think so. SRCFILES contains the files, but I talk about the dirs. Read the link I gave you. VPATH is a special variable that GNU make will interpret. It will look in the paths of VPATH for the sources that are in a target's prerequisites. .

Comment: @TimF As long as there aren't two sources with the same name (like the usual `main.c`, since they are different programs). In that case `VPATH` will bring endless amounts of pain and suffering. The `vpath` directive might be more useful.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo life is clearly easier when all you file names are unique. Unfortunately in my case I face this situation and can't change it. Believe me, if you have the choice, you'd better stick to this rule.

Comment: @TimF I know :) I was just pointing a possible pitfall of the `VPATH` approach.

Comment: @yabhishek Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39604692/6644919) of mine could help you? It's almost the same thing, just have to tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems: constructing a list of the files you want to build, and writing a rule or set of rules to build them. As it happens, both problems are made difficult by Make's lack of good wildcard handling.

The first part:

```
SRCFILES := $(wildcard */*.c)

EXECFILES := $(join $(addsuffix executables/,$(dir $(SRCFILES))), $(basename $(notdir $(SRCFILES))))
```

Crude, but effective.

The second part requires associating a target name (`dir1/executables/q1)` with the corresponding source name (`dir1/q1.c`). Perhaps the least horrible way to do this is with a pattern rule that uses SECONDEXPANSION to manipulate the target name:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXECFILES): $$(addsuffix .c,$$(subst executables/,,$$@))
    @echo building $@ from $<
    -$(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

There's some controversy about the best way to build directories, but I like this approach:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(EXECFILES): $$(addsuffix .c,$$(subst executables/,,$$@)) $$(dir $$@)
    @echo building $@ from $<
    -$(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

%/executables:
    mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Previously I was using pattern substitution approach to get the path of executables as:   ``EXECFILES = $(patsubst %/*c, $(join $(join %,executables), $(basename $(notdir %))), $(SRCFILES))``      and was getting contents of $(SRCFILES) every time. I searched for alternatives but couldn't find until your answer. Thanks again !!