# How to code makefile when source files are in various directories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── makefile
└── src
    ├── subsys1
    │   ├── includes
    │   └── src_1.cpp
    └── subsys2
        ├── includes
        └── src_2.cpp
```

I have written a makefile to build executable 'myapp' from the above source files:

```
print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)

# Application name
APP := myapp

# Set the directory to store the object files in
OBJDIR_R = _gnuRelease
OBJDIR_D = _gnuDebug

# Names of compiler and linker, and their associated switches
CXX:=g++
LINKER:=g++
CXXFLAGS+=-Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -lpthread -m64

ifeq ($(DEBUG),1)
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR_D)
CXXFLAGS += -g
else
OBJDIR := $(OBJDIR_R)
CXXFLAGS += -O2
endif

LDFLAGS =

# Set the name of the output executable
EXEFILE := LedaAP

VPATH = ../src/subsys1 ../src/subsys2

CPP_FILES = src_1.cpp src_2.cpp

OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(CPP_FILES))

DEP_FILES = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.d,$(CPP_FILES))

INC_DIRS := ../src/subsys1/includes ../src/subsys2/includes
INC_SWITCHES=$(foreach d, $(INC_DIRS), -I$d)

# This default target builds the executable by linking the object files
$(APP) : $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LINKER) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

# A rule to build an .o file from a .cpp file
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_SWITCHES) -c $< -o $@

# Running 'make clean' deletes the executables and all the libraries.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo Deleting executables and libraries. Use make clean_exe to delete just the executables.
    @rm -f $(OBJDIR_D)/$(EXEFILE)
    @rm -f $(OBJDIR_R)/$(EXEFILE)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR_D)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR_R)
```

The result is object files and executable in the build directory:

```
build
├── makefile
├── myapp
├── src_1.o
└── src_2.o
```

I actually want:

```
build
├── _gnuRelease
│   ├── myapp
│   └── objects
│       ├── src_1.o
│       └── src_2.o
└── makefile
```

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Hi David, I had a similar question some time ago. Please check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make

Comment: Thank you, that is a very helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the line: `CPP_FILES = src_1.cpp src_2.cpp` it's better practice to put the directory names in there (i.e. `CPP_FILES = subsys1/src_1.cpp subsys2/src_2.cpp`).  First, this avoids problems if the two subsystems happen to have a file with the same name, and second, it makes your makefile simpler, and easier to maintain.

If you're intent on doing things your way, you prepend a directory to the OBJ_FILES: `OBJ_FILES=$(SOURCE_FILES:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)`, and modify the pattern rule accordingly: `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp`, which will place the .o files in the proper directory.

Comment: <DavidA here from different account> Thanks for your answer. I agree that specifying each src file with directory name is better. However, my difficulty is that to then produce the obj file paths I need to strip off the directory and replace it with my desired object file path.  So, using patsubst how could I strip off '../subsys1/' or '../subsys2/ and replace with OBJDIR?  Especially as in the real project I also have some files in '../../some_dir/'.  Can regular expressions be used?

Comment: @user1768576: `$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(SOURCE_FILES)))`

Comment: Thanks. So I now have: `CPP_FILES = ../src/subsys1/src_1.cpp ../src/subsys1/src_2.cpp

OBJ_FILES_TMP = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(CPP_FILES))
OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(notdir $(OBJ_FILES_TMP)))` but my dependency rule is still: `%.o: %.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC_SWITCHES) -c $< -o $@` so when I run make I get `no rule to make target _gnuRelease/src_1.o needed by myapp`.  How do I modify this dependency rule to cope with the path change?

Comment: Ok, you're mixing up a couple of things.  You're still building all the .o files into a flat directory, which would be problematic if there are name conflicts down the road.  It should be something like:  `CPP_FILES = subsys1/src_1.cpp subsys2/src_2.cpp`, and then `$(OBJFILES)=$(SOURCE_FILES:%.cpp=%.o)`, and then you could do: `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : ../src/%.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile documented at [Building C-program “out of source tree” with GNU make](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033569/4940771) and referred to by @k-mulier above satisfies my requirements.