# placing object files in different directories in nonrecursive build

Tags: makefile, build, autotools, autoconf, automake

**Background**

We build `.mex` files for both Matlab and Octave. The source code is common to both Matlab and Octave but with slight modifications here and there (taken care of via macro conditionals in the code). For reference, the source structure is:

```
                      mex/
                       |
              ------------------------------
              |                            |
           sources/                      build/
              |                            |
        -----------            -------------------------------
        |         |            |          |        |         |
       mex1/ ... mexN/       octave/  mex1.am ... mexN.am  matlab/
        |                      |                             |
    -----------           -------------                -------------
    |         |           |           |                |           |
file1.cc ... fileM.cc  configure.ac  Makefile.am   configure.ac  Makefile.am
```

The `.mex` source files are located in `mex/sources/mex*/` and we compile multiple `.mex` files.

The Matlab build system is located in `mex/build/matlab/`, where we run './configure' to locate the headers/libraries needed to link against for the compilation of Matlab `.mex` files. Analogous `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` files exist in `/mex/build/octave/`, modified to find the Octave headers and libraries.

The automake build instructions (the paths to the source files, the `.mex` files to be built) common to both Matlab and Octave exist in the files named `/mex/build/mex*.am` and typically look like:

```
mexI_PROGRAMS += mexI

nodist_mexI_SOURCES = \
    ../../sources/mexI/mexI.c \
    ../../sources/mexI/mexI_file1.c \
    ../../sources/mexI/mexI_fileN.c
```

Recursive make worked perfectly for our setup (we used to have directories named `/mex/build/matlab/mex*/` and `/mex/build/octave/mex*/` that contained `Makefile.am` files; object files would be compiled there and the output files would be located there). Now we are moving to a non-recursive build given the changes that GNU `subdir-objects` change. Starting with the Matlab build, I was able to modify it to work non-recursively without any problems.

**The Problem**

In moving to the non-recursive build, object files are now produced in the same directories as their source files, *i.e.,* `/mex/sources/mex*/`. As I have already compiled the Matlab `.mex` files, the `*.o` files exist in these source directories. So, when I go compile the Octave files, `make` skips directly to the linking step as it already sees the recent `*.o` files in the directory. The problem is, of course, that these `*.o` files were compiled with Matlab headers and hence will not work in an Octave build.

The easiest solution would be to simply define a directory in which the object file would be placed. Currently, a typical build compilation command looks like (removing flags):

```
gcc ... -o ../../sources/mex1/mex1.o ../../sources/mex1/mex1.c
```

*I would just like to change the location of the file passed to the `-o` flag, but don't see how to do this in automake.* Unless, of course, there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: So, in your problem descritpion you alrady give an answer. Simply define a directory in which object files will be placed. And name that directory differently for matlab and for octave objects. It will require some `GNU make` functions and/or some `bash` scripting, I guess...

Comment: @igagis thanks for your response. If I write a script to move the `.o.` files to a different directory, won't `make` recompile everything on a subsequent run as opposed to just those files that have changed? Also then I'd have to write specific linking rules and couldn't use those created by `autoconf`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Moving the objects files is not a good idea for the reason you mention. Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make/39033569#39033569) here, I think it could suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would just like to change the location of the file passed to the -o flag, but don't see how to do this in automake. Unless, of course, there's a more elegant solution.

I observe in the first place that the compiled object files are being placed next to the source files because *that's what you said to do* by giving Automake the `subdir-objects` option and performing an in-source build (or in fact two).  There are several options for having them placed somewhere else, but two of them stand out, as they are tied directly to the reasons for the problem:

1. Remove the `subdir-objects` Automake option.  Your intermediate .o files should then end up in the build directory from which you run `make`.  This is a little messy, but that should not be a concern, as the generated Makefile knows which files they are, and can therefore distinguish them from the installable products where necessary.  The main issue here is that you could run into trouble with collisions among the object files associated with different `.mex` files built for the same target.
2. Perform out-of-source instead of in-source builds, one for each main target (octave / matlab), each in its own build tree.  Contrary to what you may think, that's *not* what you're doing now, at least not from the Autotools' perspective.  When you perform an out-of-source build, all generated files are written to the build tree, so having separate build trees for octave and matlab should resolve your issue cleanly.  This is the option I recommend.

The Autotools provide support for out-of-source building automatically.  All you need to do is create the desired build directory, make that your working directory, and then run the project's `configure` script from there.  The build directory can be a subdirectory of the source root if you wish, though it doesn't have to be.  The key thing to understand is the the "top source directory" is the one containing the `configure` script, and the "top build directory" is the one that was the working directory from which you ran that script.  Thus, if you were in the project root, you might do this:

```
$ cd build
$ mkdir build-octave build-matlab

$ cd build-octave
$ ../octave/configure
$ make
$ make install

$ cd ../build-matlab
$ ../matlab/configure
$ make
$ make install
```

But it is possible to write your `Makefile.am` files in ways that break that support by assuming in-source building.  The `Makefile.am` excerpt you present does precisely that by depending on a specific relative path from the build directory to the sources.  If your `Makefile.am` wants to refer to a source file (as opposed to a built file) relative to the top source directory, then it can use the automatic `$(top_srcdir)` variable provided by Automake.  (And that will not interfere with in-source building, either.)  For example, you ought to be able to do this:

```
nodist_mexI_SOURCES = \
    $(top_srcdir)/../../sources/mexI/mexI.c \
    $(top_srcdir)/../../sources/mexI/mexI_file1.c \
    $(top_srcdir)/../../sources/mexI/mexI_fileN.c
```

I don't so much like referring to resources *above* the top source directory, but it ought to work.

---

**Update:**

Consider also modifying the Autotooling to have only one build system for both target types.  Autoconf supports defining your own `--enable` and `--with` options, which you can use to select the target type at the time you run `configure`.  Autoconf and Automake support conditionals of various kinds that can use these and other criteria to adjust the details of the build.  This could be a big win over maintaining parallel build systems separately.  This could all work together very nicely with out-of-source building.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to answer @John Bollinger. When I try `1.` and `2.`, I get the same warnings I get in my current build system when I run `autoreconf -si`: `automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects' automake option hasn't been enabled.` Getting rid of this warning is the reason I have undertaken these changes. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: BTW, my current idea, which seems to be working, is to soft link the source files into `mex/build/matlab/mexI` directories by providing `Makefile.am` with a `BUILT_SOURCES` argument that links them in.

Comment: @houtanb, your question says that the problem is with object file collisions between the two builds.  This is what I have answered.  If that is not what you really want to know about, then do edit your question to clarify, or even ask an entirely new question.

Comment: @houtanb, and if you do so then be sure to provide a [mcve], including, but by no means limited to, the versions of the autotools that you are using.  In my tests, I do not get warnings about not using `subdir-objects`.

Comment: @houtanb, BTW, soft-linking sources is an old, well-known idea.  It can work, but it is a messy, inferior alternative to VPATH-based out-of-source building such as the Autotools and GNU `make` provide for free.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340991/vpath-out-of-source-build. Thanks for your help