# Makefile for many subfolders

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following folder structure:

```
├── build
├── external
│   ├── build
│   ├── lib1
│   │   ├── lib1Classes.cc
│   │   └── lib1Classes.h
│   ├── lib2
│   │   ├── lib2Classes.cc
│   │   └── lib2Classes.h
│   ├── lib3
│   │   ├── lib3Classes.cc
│   │   └── lib3Classes.h
│   └── Makefile
├── include
│   ├── SomeClass.h
│   └── SomeOtherClass.h
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── SomeClass.cc
    └── SomeOtherClass.cc
```

I am trying to first compile libXClasses.cc and libXClasses.h into ./external/build/libX.o, then combine all libX.o into an ./external/build/external.so. 
In step 2 I'd like to compile SomeClass.h and SomeClass.cc into ./build/SomeClass.o and SomeOtherClass.h, SomeOtherClass.cc into ./build/SomeOtherClass.o. Finally I want to link ./external/build/external.o and ./build/*.o into a binary in ./build.

I am however already failing in step 1. My idea for ./external/Makefile was something like this:

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++11

TARGET ?= external.so
BUILD_DIR ?= ./build

# get all source files
SRCS = $(shell find . -name *.cc -or -name *.cpp -or -name *.h)
# get the name of all directories that contain at least one source file
SRC_DIRS ?= $(foreach src,$(SRCS),$(shell dirname $(src)))
# remove duplicate directories
SRC_DIRS := $(shell echo $(SRC_DIRS) | xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs)
# define one target object file foreach .cc source file
OBJS := $(foreach srcd,$(SRC_DIRS),$(BUILD_DIR)/$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(shell find $(srcd) -name *.cc -printf "%f\n")))

# rule to build ./external/build/external.so
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared $(OBJS) -o $@

# no idea how to build libX.o in one rule
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cc %.h
    $(CXX) -c -fpic $< -o $@
```

This does not work as in the last rule I am not specifying where the correct .cc and .h come from. But I don't know how I could do that at all. Do I have to write a rule for each libX directory separately? What if I have 10 or 20 libX directories?

Cheers!

Comment: What step, specifically does not work?

Comment: Building the libX.o files in ./external/build.. I just don't know how to tell make to combine the following rules into one:

`
    build/lib1.o: lib1/lib1Classes.cc lib1/lib1Classes.h
        $(CXX) -c -fpic $< -o $@

    build/lib2.o: lib2/lib2Classes.cc lib2/lib2Classes.h
        $(CXX) -c -fpic $< -o $@

    build/lib3.o: lib3/lib3Classes.cc lib3/lib3Classes.h
        $(CXX) -c -fpic $< -o $@
`

Comment: One solution is to put your *.o files in a common output directory regardless of where it's source file comes from.

Comment: I am already trying to do that. The common output directory is external/build or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: (_It's a long time since I played with Makefiles, so there may be new bits I don't know about, but..._) You should be able to make a generic "build libX.o" rule (and what you've got _may_ be it), but I _think_ you have to list `lib1.o`, `lib2.o` etc. as explicit dependencies of _something_ (probably `external.so`) so it knows the list of things it needs to apply that generic rule to.

Comment: My first rule should do that right? I mean it basically says: 

build/external.so: build/lib1.o build/lib2.o build/lib3.o

but I think in the second rule make doesn't know which .cc and .h files to take so it doesn't execute the second rule.

Comment: You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make/39033569#39033569), with a few modifications you should be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: create a list of the `libX` directories (because no one wants to maintain a list like that by hand):

```
LIBS := $(wildcard external/lib*)
```

Step 2: create a list of the source files:

```
LIB_SRCS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cc, $(LIBS))))
```

(I've removed the paths because they're a pain; there's more than one way to do this.)

Step 3: create a list of desired object files:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst lib%Classes.cc, external/build/lib%.o, $(LIB_SRCS))
```

Step 4: write a rule to build these files:

```
vpath %.cc $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): external/build/lib%.o: lib%Classes.cc
    $(CXX) -c -fPIC -I$(dir $<) $< -o $@
```

(Step 5: write a rule to build the library, but you already have that.)

One could do more. This makefile does not detect the fact that `libN.o` depends on `libNClasses.h`. It is possible to set that up, but it's a little complicated, and this is enough for one day.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But since this still does not cover the dependence on the header files I decided to switch to CMake.