# What is the exact chain of events when GNU make updates the .d files?

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following simple makefile:

```
#------------------------------#
#    List all object files     #
#------------------------------#
objects := main.o foo.o bar.o baz.o

#------------------------------#
#    Define pattern rule       #
#    for   *.c -> *.o          #
#------------------------------#
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#------------------------------#
#    Define the rule to make   #
#    the end result            #
#------------------------------#
.PHONY all
all: myApp.elf

myApp.elf: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(objects) -o myApp.elf $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

If you give the command `make all`, GNU make will start at the target `myApp.elf`. It looks at all the prerequisites `main.o`, `foo.o`, `bar.o` and `baz.o` and attempts to update them.

To do that, make uses the pattern rule defined in the middle of the makefile. This pattern rule expands like this:

```
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) main.c -o main.o

foo.o: foo.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) foo.c -o foo.o

bar.o: bar.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) bar.c -o bar.o

baz.o: baz.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) baz.c -o baz.o
```

So far, so good. But you can clearly see that dependencies (included h-files) are missing.

I found some sources that recommend the following approach:

```
#------------------------------#
#    List all object files     #
#    and all dependency files  #
#------------------------------#
objects := main.o foo.o bar.o baz.o
deps := $(objects:.o=.d)

#------------------------------#
#    Define pattern rule       #
#    for   *.c -> *.o          #
#------------------------------#
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP $< -o $@

#------------------------------#
#    Define the rule to make   #
#    the end result            #
#------------------------------#
.PHONY all
all: myApp.elf

myApp.elf: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(objects) -o myApp.elf $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

-include $(deps)
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around this approach. First GNU make reads the makefile and looks for other included makefiles (see GNU make manual paragraph 3.5 "How Makefiles Are Remade"). Make attempts to update each included makefile it can find (in this case the dependency files `main.d`, `foo.d`, `bar.d` and `baz.d`) before starting execution of the makefiles. I've summarized this in the following figure:

[image]

Exactly. I don't see any rule where the dependency files are specified as targets.

Please help me to understand what actually happens next. Please, write your answer as a step-by-step chain of events. That would be great to gain insight in the matter.

**Note:**
Of course, the `-MMD` and `-MP` arguments in the compilation command (see pattern rule in the middle) lead to dependency files getting created. But the targets of this pattern rule are the *object*-files, not the *dependency*-files.

**Note:**
I had wrongly assumed that GNU make has an implicit rule getting activated here. But thanks to your comments and answers, I now know this was wrong :-)

Comment: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ Nuff said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens when you run `make` after `make clean` and dependency files don't exist yet:

1. `make` reads the text and reaches `-include` directive.
2. For each argument of the `-include` directive `make` tries to find a rule that has it as a target and run that rule.  `make` does this as part of processing of `-include` directive. No such rule will be found, because you didn't provide one.
3. `make` attempts to read files specified in `-include` directive and just skips those which don't exist (all of them in this case).
4. `make` goes to build the project, which in turn creates those `*.d` files.

If you run `make` again:

1. [same as before]
2. [same as before]
3. Since files do exist now, `make` reads them.
4. [same as before]

You might notice that this implies that `make` uses dependencies from the previous run, which is exactly how it works.
Dependencies lag behind changes in the source files.
This doesn't usually cause inconveniences though, and when it does removing dependency files can be used to fix the build.

Comment: Hi Xaizek,
Thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful! You wrote that **`make` uses dependencies from the previous run.** Isn't that dangerous?

Comment: Not really dangerous. If you remove a file but the dependency is still there the build might fail. If you add a new file, it will be built either way. If you change a file, it will be built. So, it's only this annoyance of having to do `make clean` after file removal or rename that's left. The are ways to avoid this, but it's usually considered to not be worth the effort.

Comment: Okay, I see. If you add a new h-file, you should include it in some c-file(s). So those c-file(s) get an extra line like `#include new.h`. And that will trigger the recompilation of those c-file(s).

Answer (score 1):

There is no [built-in `make` rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for `.d` files. You can see that that `make` does consider rebuilding `.d` files with `make -d`, but there is no rule, e.g:

```
Reading makefile 'test/debug/library.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file 'test/debug/library.d'.
  File 'test/debug/library.d' does not exist.
  Looking for an implicit rule for 'test/debug/library.d'.
  No implicit rule found for 'test/debug/library.d'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'test/debug/library.d'.
 Must remake target 'test/debug/library.d'.
 Failed to remake target file 'test/debug/library.d'.
```

In the above output `make` checks whether `library.d` needs to be updated. Failing to find a rule for it, `make` skips updating it, see [How Makefiles Are Remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles):

> ... after reading in all makefiles, `make` will consider each as a goal target and attempt to update it. **If a makefile has a rule which says how to update it (found either in that very makefile or in another one) or if an implicit rule applies to it, it will be updated if necessary**.

And this is why it does not compile each `.c` twice.

You can print all the rules, including the built-ins, using `make --print-data-base`.

Comment: Hi @Maxim Egorushkin, thank you very much for your answer. I have updated my question to give more details :-)

Comment: @K.Mulier Updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer both questions together as it makes more sense.

Make has no built-in rule for `.d` - it doesn't need one. `-MMD -MP` instructs the *compiler* to output dependencies as part of compilation proper.

If you think about it this is exactly what you want, as the only time you need to update a dependency file is if the relative source file has changed itself, if dependencies are generated during compilation you only need to run the compiler once to generate both the `.d` and `.o` files.

The last piece of the puzzle is `-include` which tells make to include dependencies if it can find them but not to worry if they aren't present, they'll be generated anyway by the compiler.

Comment: Hi @user657267, thank you very much for your answer. I have updated my question to give more details :-)