# Can't assign a list of file names to a variable in GNU-make

Tags: c, makefile, dependency-management, avr

First post here, not native english speaker, glad to post and help others!

I'm having a problem using make to compile an avr-gcc project for me. More specifically in assigning a list of *.c source files of different directories, (subdirectories in my case), to a variable in make, where it will be used to generate dependencies.

Using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787217) method i found, *Renaud Pacalet* uses this syntax:

```
SRC = $(shell find src/ -name "*.cpp")
```

Using the find command in my case looks like this:

```
SOURCE_FILES = $(shell find -name '*.c')
```

And the result is (on cmd):

```
C:\AVR_projetos\Balizar_reserva>find -name '*.c'
./main.c
./modules/i2c/i2c.c
./modules/rom/rom.c
```

But, when make invokes shell to perform the script, the variable only holds the first filename in the sequence.

So far i tried:

- Using $(wildcard *.c) function, same problem
- Using $(shell echo *.c), same problem
- Using the additional arguments -print0 to -find to force a in-line output, still nothing
- Using $(shell find (path) -name '*.c') using an absolute path to the main directory, a relative ../, and all in combination with the additional arguments

Also, I've referred to these two manual pages:

- [Shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)
- [Wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function)

Both of them explain in a simple way that this is possible, I do the same thing and get nothing.

- This is my file directory: [Image](https://prnt.sc/qs3td0)
- And my make file (it's all over the place because I was trying to implement this): [Paste bin](https://pastebin.com/5kugNTfJ)

For the record, i had a problem before having this problem:

```
avr-gcc -MM main.c > depend.d
  0 [main] sh 14484 sync_with_child: child 15780(0x1DC) died before initialization with status code 0xC0000142
158 [main] sh 14484 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
/usr/bin/sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable make: *** [depend] Error 128
```

For which i found [This fix](https://www.madwizard.org/electronics/articles/winavrvista) that seens to work.

- Os: Windows 10 professional 1903 comp. 18362.535
- GNU-make: 3.81

Comment: One difference is that 'his' includes a directory name (`src/`) and yours does not.  Maybe `$(shell find . -name '*.c')`?  It may not be the issue, but …

Comment: Nitpick, but isn't it always a good idea to specify a path for the find command?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference in make files (esp on Windows) or not, but unix shells (like bash) have very different behaviours for single-quotes ('), double-quotes (") and no-quotes.   His example used double-quotes `"*.cpp"`, so I'd copy that.    (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash )

Comment: Could you add `@echo "rule: $@ on $^"` as first command in your `%o:` and `depend:` rules (and edit your post to see the result)

Comment: And do not hesitate to post a [MCVE]

Comment: I see you are running on Windows.  In Windows the way make determines the shell may be different: it's much harder than on POSIX systems because (a) there may not be a POSIX shell available and (b) some people want command.com.  Also in Windows, there is a command.com version of `find` which is different than the POSIX version of `find`.  My suspicion is that make's `shell` function is invoking  the Windows `find`, or something like that.

Comment: @racraman i have tried using double quotes as Renaud Pacalet used, but for some reason my makefile give me an error, and this was before a have fixed another bug that prevented my make file to be executed correctly because it didn't find a correct shell. So i used [This fix](https://www.madwizard.org/electronics/articles/winavrvista) and restarted my pc, now the makefile accepts double quotes without any error, and i can generate the dependency files correctly. So, thank you very much :).

Comment: This [explains an alternative](https://blog.jgc.org/2011/07/gnu-make-recursive-wildcard-function.html) not using shell.

Comment: OT: Please do not cuss when writing comments and/or answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions, i really appreciate that. Got the damn thing to work by using the following command:

```
$(shell find -name "*.c")
```

That way we can can assign it to a variable and use it. With this, we can use the following makefile to the corresponding proposed project structure.

- [Makefile](https://pastebin.com/i3553enL) (comments in portuguese)

This project is setup for avr-gcc programming, however, this concept applies to normal c and cpp programming.
File structure (an example, where i2c can be a generic module and avr_config.h a special header when compiling avr-gcc related projects):

```
.
├── modules
│   └── i2c
│       ├── i2c.c
│       └── i2c.h
├── main.c
├── Makefile
└── avr_config.h
```

There can be as many modules as you want since the variable

```
SOURCE_FILES = $(shell find -name "*.c")
```

Capture all of them. I setup this the simplest way it could be done, so by consequence, object files will be compiled side by side with the source and header files an then linked together in the main directory. 
Also a file named

```
depend.d
```

Will be created in order to compilation to be done.

The makefile also contains some useful commands that are described in the beggining of the file.

Hope this helps someone! A dedicated post will be made, explaining all the context and how to setup a generic avr-gcc project to microcontroller programming in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO,
as You mentioned you refer to wildcard function, but description says:

> One use of the wildcard function is to get a list of all the C source files in a directory, like this: `$(wildcard *.c)`.

Then I think when you executed Make, main.c compiled?

You need to improve your wildcard to search for subdirectories or manualy add them.
Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038459/10921202) and question.

Comment: I looked into it, but unfortunately it didn't work either, but i got it to work using  - $(shell find -name "*.c")