# Portable C Makefile for extended library

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to understand how makefiles work for a long time (however, quite inhomogeneously). I think, even though there is a hole bunch of discussion about makefiles, this is the first template that kind of lays out the structure and seems general enough, so I hope, that moderators will not close the question.

I have several parts of code in different c-files, but all in the same folder:

1)frprmn.c

2)mnbrak.c

3)nrutil.c

4)linmin.c

5)f1dim.c

6)dbrent.c

These codes are from Numerical Recipes and can be found elsewhere.

The main-function is in frprmn.c. The makefile is

```
program_NAME := MINIMIZE
program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard frprmn.c mnbrak.c nrutil.c linmin.c f1dim.c dbrent.c)
#program_CXX_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.c=.o}
#program_CXX_OBJS := ${program_CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
#program_OBJS := $(program_C_OBJS) $(program_CXX_OBJS)
#program_INCLUDE_DIRS :=
#program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=
#program_LIBRARIES :=

#CPPFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
#LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
#LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

.PHONY: all clean distclean

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
@- $(RM) $(program_NAME)
@- $(RM) $(program_OBJS)

distclean: clean
```

The "template" for the makefile is from [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile). I was trying to follow the explanations when modifying it. By no means I have expected it to work as I don't get the following things:

1. Why don't we need header-files to link the libraries. Or do we? Maybe the author of the tutorial relies on it as common knowledge...
2. Why would I need an object file for each c-file? I need only one: frprmn.c. How do I do that?
3. How does makefile know which file contains main-function?
4. When I run it, I get the following error

   c++      -o MINIMIZE
   clang: error: no input files
   make: *** [MINIMIZE] Error 1

I have no idea how it comes that I got c++ there. According to the tutorial, I have commented out all the c++-related lines. My guess is that it used C++ compiler as the default one, in which case, how to tell it to use gcc without forcing it explicitly?

6. All the placeholders, well, even thought I don't need them in this case, I still would like to be able to used them eventually. What do I do with

> foreach includedir

Do I just list them there?

Can somebody give an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site, your question is too broad, please read the manual of make before asking question. P.S: wildcard is a very bad practice.

Comment: @Stargateur I can shrink the question to "how to make it work without oversimplifying the template?", if it makes everyone feel better. I am asking this question namely because of the tutorials that answer only narrow questions. I don't expect short answers. If you can point to good references or answer it in part (that is why it is structured accordingly), I will be more than happy!

Comment: @Stargateur Also, for every question there is a manual, unless it is a bug... The same as for every course there is a book... haha... Why wildcard is a bad practice? Do you have a reference, or can explain it?

Comment: You may want to look at [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make/39033569#39033569) to have a complete, detailed and commented example of a Makefile. It will however not explain how the other parts of the toolchain (compiler, linker) work.

Comment: @MsTais I said that because looking by your understanding of makefile you didn't read the manuel. A bad tutorial isn't enough, you should read the manuel and them try the tutorial. It's like "how to you speak french ?" "did you read the manuel ?" "no, why, I follow a tutorial". Answer this question will resume to rewrite the [manuel of make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: 1) That is a C question, not a Make question. 2) `make frprmn.o` 3) It doesn't; the compiler searches for `main`. 4) `program_OBJS` is empty, perhaps you meant `program_C_OBJS`. ("...how to tell it to use gcc without forcing it explicitly?" *What?*) 6) Those are tools you do not yet need; consult the manual if you want to learn them.

Comment: @Beta 4) In the manual that I have referenced, the author says that it is a "bad practice" to forcefully say which compiler to use. It is better to let makefile find the default compiler using built-in functions. But when I do that, for some reason it uses c++, it seems like. I do not want to say gcc in makefile, but I want it to think that gcc is the default compiler. Thanks for your response!