# Clean way to write a Makefile to perform an out of source build

Tags: c++, makefile, build

Using the simple scenario of a folder structure with a project folder where in this root there is a build and a sources folder:

```
project
- build
- sources
```

In the sources folder there is hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

and a Makefile:

```
SOURCE_DIRECTORIES = ../ch1

vpath %.cpp $(SOURCE_DIRECTORIES)

hello: hello.cpp
    g++ ${SOURCE_DIRECTORIES}/hello.cpp -o hello
```

I run like this from build folder:

```
make -f ../sources/Makefile
```

The above works but the vpath isn't so useful.  Even with vpath I have to add the SOURCE_DIRECTORIES path the the command line.  I might as well not use vpath and just use $(SOURCE_DIRECTORIES) where required.

It is also a little brittle in that the build folder has to be at the same level as the sources folder.  But I can live with that.

Is this the best approach?  I am thinking there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: you can use cmake!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building C-program "out of source tree" with GNU make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015453/building-c-program-out-of-source-tree-with-gnu-make)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `vpath`, here's a way to have the `makefile` in your sources directory and let it use a `BUILD` variable with the build directory in question:

```
-include makefile.in # optionally read in config file

BUILD ?= build # or some other default...

$(BUILD)/hello: $(BUILD)/hello.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<

$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

This way, the default is to output everything in `src/build` (hence, no real out-of-source-build), but you can simply change that behavior with a `makefile.in` "configuration" file, which could simply be

```
BUILD = ../build
```

This is sufficient as in the `makefile`, `BUILD ?=` makes sure the variable is only set to the right hand side if it's not defined yet.

Comment: I am having problems running this. I have created makefile.in in source folder. Tried running from build folder but then get makefile.in: no such file or directory

Comment: I see... this is setup to be invoked from the source directory. Does that work? Also note that the `-` in front of the `include` is essential to make the existence of `makefile.in` optional.

Comment: It works from source folder - good..  However, with no makefile.in get make: *** No rule to make target '%.cpp', needed by 'build'. Stop.

Comment: The issue is that the default build directory doesn't exist. If no `makefile.in` is found, `BUILD` is initialized to `build`, hence the `makefile` assumes an existing directory called `build` in the sources directory. If you create that one, it should work. You can also change the default `BUILD` to something like `BUILD ?= ../build`.

Comment: Hm... are you using GNU make? Maybe something in this makefile is specific to the GNU implementation of `make`?!

Comment: yes using gnu make on ubuntu.  Its ok, I can investigate, but running from source does what I want